# how to take off time in date time tabular model

Tags: t-sql, data-warehouse, powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have a date dimension table and I have a Date column in that table it  has datekey, fulldatekey, Date, DayofMonth, Dayofyear, month,  ect. the Date column only has yyyy-mm-dd, but when I bring it into my tabular cube model it appends a 12:00:00 A.M time to the end of it. I was wanting to know how do I remove the time to only have the date. I am building a tabular cube in ssdt to bring into power bi

Comment: Make your table a Date Table and transform datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/679.power-bi-dax-date-and-time-function),

> In contrast to Microsoft Excel, which stores dates as a serial number,
>   PowerPivot date functions always return a datetime data type. However,
>   you can use formatting to display dates as serial numbers if you want.

From my "limited" experience, you can change the date formatting in one column, but when you reference it from another column, it will once again include the 12:00:00 AM time as part of the date when it displays in the new column. I assume this is because, as Microsoft says in that website,"PowerPivot date functions always return a datetime data type."

Comment: so what I ended up doing is just making a calculated column and getting the substring of the date field. prob not the best way but it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Edit Query -> Transform Tab -> Choose Data Type

That's my best guess.